# How to order by the sum of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a query that calculates the total sales by month,

the basics of the select clause looks like this

```
SELECT
MID.menu_item_id,
ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(CASE WHEN CSD.tendered_date_time BETWEEN 
CONVERT(datetime,'2016-07-01 06:00:00:000') AND CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-01 
05:59:59:999')THEN CID.consumed_quantity END,0)),0) 
AS [JUL],
```

This cycles through various month. I would like to sum the total across all of these months and then order by this sum in a descending manner - so we have a list of menu_item_ids ordered by their total sales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would add another column:

```
SELECT MID.menu_item_id,
       SUM(CID.consumed_quantity) as total
       SUM(CASE WHEN CSD.tendered_date_time BETWEEN 
CONVERT(datetime,'2016-07-01 06:00:00.000') AND CONVERT(datetime, '2016-08-01 
05:59:59.999') THEN CID.consumed_quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [JUL],
       . . .
. . .
ORDER BY SUM(CID.consumed_quantity) DESC;
```